# Como redimensionar imagem independente do tamanho?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Segue o código abaixo:

```
public FileContentResult Foto_Pequeno()
{
    byte[] byte_image = null;
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Imagem WHERE Id = '1'";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                byte_image = (byte[])reader["Image"];
            }
        }
    }
    return new FileContentResult(byte_image, "image/png");
}
```

No banco de dados está gravado como varbinary(MAX), o tamanho da imagem está como 946x456. Como faço para redimensionar a imagem se ela for maior que 100x100. Como altura e largura.

É possivel redimensionar image byte array para 100 x 100 ?

Comment: Você tem esses valores 946x456 como padrão? outra pergunta 100 x 100 não vai ficar distorcido? um recorte até até dá pelo tamanho!!!

Comment: Sim 946x456 é o tamanho padrão.  O 100x100 é só um teste. Quero um exemplo de diminuir o tamanho da imagem.

Comment: Nesse caso de where Id = 1 tem tamanho padrão de 946x456, se for where Id = 2 tem outro tamanho diferente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com a classe [***WebImage***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage(v=vs.111).aspx) e o comando `Resize` pode conseguir com êxito redimensionar sua imagem.

***Exemplo Minimo:***

```
public FileContentResult Imagem()
{
    byte[] content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Image/") + "1.jpg");
    WebImage webImage = new WebImage(content);
    webImage.Resize(100, 100, true, false);
    content = webImage.GetBytes();
    return new FileContentResult(content, "image/jpg");
}
```

***No seu caso em particular:***

```
public FileContentResult Foto_Pequeno()
{
    byte[] byte_image = null;
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Imagem WHERE Id = '1'";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(
                      ConfigurationManager
                               .ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                byte_image = (byte[])reader["Image"];
            }
        }
    }    
    WebImage webImage = new WebImage(byte_image);
    webImage.Resize(100, 100, true, false);
    byte_image = webImage.GetBytes();
    return new FileContentResult(byte_image, "image/jpg");
}
```

Essa classe também possui o métodos:

- `Crop` (recorte),
- `AddImageWatermark` (marca d'agua) e
- `AddTextWatermark` (texto como marca d'agua).

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [WebImage Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage(v=vs.111).aspx)
- [WebImage Helper in Web API](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/2b481f/webimage-helper-in-web-api/)

Comment: Não sabia esse "WebImage" trabalhou certinho aqui.

Comment: Uma dúvida, WebImage permite alterar só pelo width ?

Comment: é sim pelo tamanho, porque?

Comment: Por nada, é só uma pergunta